# How do I make a shopping list from multiple recipes in an SQL database?

Tags: sql, many-to-many, shopping-cart, recipe

I'm working on using a recipe database in SQLw, like the one in this question (which has helped a lot already) [Structuring a recipe database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4029686/structuring-a-recipe-database) , to combine the ingredients of several user selected recipes to a shopping list.

Also, the items on this shopping list are to be divided in two categories (eg: "groceries" and "check pantry")

Example case:

1. User can select 7 recipes to make a weekly mealplan in a form (almost got this part)
2. The given output is a shopping list of all the ingredients marked as "groceries" and a "check stock" list of all the ingredients marked as "pantry".

Any help at all would be much appreciated!

Comment: homework?  have you tried to write the query at all?  you will be counting the required items, and you will then subtract the available pantry items - this equals the shopping list.

Comment: Does the user mark a specific item as "groceries" or "pantry"?  Or is this something that is going to be universal to everyone (ex. broccoli is ALWAYS marked "groceries") and thus can be stored in your database?

Answer (score 2):

I had just posted a full solution, but given the subject here looks like it may be homework, I'm just going to point you in the right direction. If this isn't homework, leave a comment and I'll put the full solution back.

Since you have multiple recipes, a normal selection based on joins would give you back multiple rows per ingredient. You want some way to roll up all of the rows for a given ingredient into a single row and show a total of the quantity that you need.